# How do you assign the result of an expression to an SQL substitution variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Can you evaluate an expression and assign the result to a substitution variable?

In my case, I need to call an old script which contains a substitutions variable.  I need to calculate a value for that variable before calling the script. I'm using Oracle SQL and SQL*Plus

Here's the basic problem:

```
def this_num = 2+2
@old_script
```

Inside old_script.sql

```
select '&this_num' from dual;  -- Probably shouldn't change this
```

Yields:
   '2+2'

Is there a way to force evaluation so that the substitution variable gets the **result** of an expression rather than the expression itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Working Solution

I found a working answer here: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#2_5

Here's the relevant text.

> 2.5 Storing a Query Column Value in a Substitution Variable
>
> Data stored in the database can be put into substitution variables:
>
> ```
> SQL> column last_name new_value mynv
> SQL> select last_name from employees where employee_id = 100;
> ```
>
> The NEW_VALUE option in the COLUMN command implicitly creates a
>   substitution variable called "mynv". The variable is not physically
>   created until a query references the column LAST_NAME. When the query
>   finishes, the variable "mynv" holds the last retrieved value from
>   column "last_name":
>
> ```
> SQL> define mynv
> DEFINE mynv      = "King" (CHAR)
> ```

So you do it like this:

```
column DUMMY_COLUMN_NAME new_value THIS_NUM
select 2+2 DUMMY_COLUMN_NAME from dual;

select '&&THIS_NUM' from dual;

'4'
------------
           4
```

Tada!

### The Evil Solution

For entertainment value, here's a really evil workaround which would break if the variable ever happens to be used outside of quotes:

```
define this_num = "' || 2+2 ||'" (CHAR)
```

Then:

```
select '&&this_num' from dual;
```

evaluates to:

```
select '' || 2+2 ||'' from dual;
```

Which yields:

### '

4

Answer (score 1):

```
def this_num = 2+2
@old_script
```

In the `old_script`, you can say

```
select &this_num from dual;
```

You don't need to use `''` around the variable name. This should work.

Comment: I would at least put parentheses around it in case it's used in other expressions, e.g. `select &this_num * 3 from dual;`

Comment: You're totally right that it's the ' marks messing this up.  I included the script to illustrate a common complication where your variable is used within legacy code that you may be forbidden-from/fearful-of editing.