# How do I set a substitution variable to the result of a query in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to do something like this in Oracle's SQL Developer (v17.2) against an Oracle 12c database:

```
define thisenv = '(select name from v$database)'
select &thisenv env, count(1) from phone;
```

I want the select to return something like this:

```
ENV      COUNT(1)
------ ----------
Dev1            7
```

If I use my sample code, I get told, effectively, that I need a group by clause because it is seeing the query instead of a string literal that is the result of the query. But adding a group by is not going to work for me.

Per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342589/how-do-you-assign-the-result-of-an-expression-to-an-sql-substitution-variable), I tried replacing the first line with

```
column dummyenv new_value thisenv
select name dummyenv from v$database;
```

I have also tried using a bind variable instead, but I still get prompted for a value for thisenv. So, those options don't work.

What else should I try?

The PHONE table looks like this:

```
PHONEID PERSONID PHONENUM     TYPE
------- -------- ------------ ----
899250  ABC12345 123-456-7890 WORK
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the `phone` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the phones in a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT name, 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM phone) as phones
  FROM v$database;
```

Alternatively, as the select privileges to the view `v$database` are often not granted, you can use the function `sys_context`. Because it is a scalar, you can just put it in the query:

```
SELECT sys_context('userenv', 'db_name') as db_name, count(*)
  FROM phone;
```

Comment: Tried that, but then I still have to group by.

Comment: Oh dear, you are absolutely right. Sorry! Fixed the query.

Comment: but that is not what you want. I'll delete the answer, ok?

Comment: I tried the sys_context(), and that worked.
`define thisenv = 'sys_context(''userenv'',''db_name'')'`

Comment: I realize this answer doesn't answer the more general nature of my question, but it satisfies the immediate need. And the function provided suggests I could code the query into a function and call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind the substitution variable - you are starting with the following SQL statement, which is syntactically incorrect:

```
select ( select name from ... ), count(1) from ...
```

- this does not fail due to the use of a substitution variable, it fails as a simple SQL statement.

If you want that output (as you show it), rewrite the query as

```
select name, ct
from   (select name from v$database)
       cross join
       (select count(1) as ct from phone);
```

Now you can use a substitution variable if need be:

```
SQL> define thisenv = '(select name from v$database)'
SQL> select name, ct
  2  from   &thisenv
  3  cross join
  4  (select count(1) as ct from phone);
```

Of course, when I run this on my machine I get an error (since I don't have a table `PHONE`), but it should work for you. It does work for me when I use an existing table name.